# where to put my icon picture for expo to use instead of default one?

Tags: react-native, icons, expo

according to expo documentation:

> The most straightforward way to provide an icon for your app is to provide the icon key in app.json

so I added my own icon to the assets folder where expo's default icons are, and modified `app.json` to point to my icon:

```
  "expo": {
     ...
     "icon": "./assets/myIcon.png"
  }
```

but when launching I get this error from expo:

> Field: icon - cannot access file at './assets/myIcon.png

what am I missing? where should I put my Icon picture?

**Solved**
by running `expo start -c` to clear cache.
*Note: it took me a few minutes to sync with my expo client app!

Comment: Is the spelling of the name of the icon correct?

Comment: @Andrew yes I'm sure it is, I also moved it to a new folder named `img` but got the same error

Comment: That is really strange.  Have you tried stopping your bundler, and then restarting with `expo start -c` to clear the cache?

Comment: @Andrew I noticed that my picture wasn't totally square with 2 or 3 pixels difference between height and width, so after fixing it, it loaded successfully thanks

Comment: You should write that up as the answer, I am glad you have gotten it solved.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not totally sure that this solved my problem because I ran `expo start -c` and edited the picture and after a few minutes my application in terminal started syncing, on the other hand I tried another picture that had some pixels difference in ratio and it threw an error about the difference in ratio, I think most probably your solution `expo start -c` solved it, let me share it

Comment: expo is not capable to do many stuff and its limited

Comment: @BlueTurtle I have written up what we discussed as an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the conversation that I had with the question poster (@Blue Turtle) there are some take aways from this.

## Image sizes

It is important to make sure that the image that you are using for your icon must be a perfect square. If it is not Expo will give an error similar to below

```
Error: Problems validating asset fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/
 • Field: icon - image should be square, but the file at './assets/icon.png' has dimensions 1242x2436.
```

The documents recommend that you use an image that has size `1024x1024` https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/#icon

> Local path or remote url to an image to use for your app's icon. We
>   recommend that you use a 1024x1024 png file. This icon will appear on
>   the home screen and within the Expo app.

## Clearing the cache

Also when updating assets etc, it is advisable to close and restart your bundler, restarting using the following command `expo start -c`. Starting the bundler this way will ensure that your cache is cleared and that any changes that you have made to packages, assets etc will be made and you will *hopefully* experience less errors.